# Inconsistent reputation count after bounty

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

I came across some mildly curious behaviour today.

- I reached the reputation cap on SO
- I started a 450 bounty
- The bounty amount was reduced from the overall reputation
- I have had two accepted answers since. Those +30 have *not* been counted towards my visible reputation score.
- They are, however, visible in the reputation audit. My reputation audit score seems to be taking the acceptances into account.

**This is not a support request. There is no problem.**  Just thought I'd report it in case it's an edge case with deeper consequences (which I doubt), and slightly curious whether this is expected behaviour.