# Can you use unearned reputation (above rep cap) for bounties?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

What is wrong with my reasoning here.:

I have 32 upvotes today.  I offered 1 50 point bounty already.  Since I have some reputation overflow that I am going to lose, I should offer another bounty on some question I asked that never got answered, right?  Its like having some free reputation to play with...

Is this wrong?

EDIT -- Im thinking my reasoning is wrong, because my daily reputation summary is stuck on +150.  So it seems that even though I have earned a potential 300+ reputation, I get stuck on +200, and then the bounties are applied after, so the final analysis number is +150.  Is that correct?

Comment: Do you get rep back from upvotes to "refill" what you use in the bounty?

Comment: @nick that is essentially what i am asking. For example, I have +150 reputations today, because I offered a 50 rep bounty.  But since I have 30+ upvotes, shouldn't I still have +200?

Comment: You could game this by trading bounties with another user that has "uncounted" rep. In this way you would be creating rep out of thin air.

Comment: @Jon - good point, didn't consider this possibility

Comment: @jon, @nick, can't you create reputation out of thin air by just upvoting?

Comment: Trading bounties would probably be easier to monitor than cross voting, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the reputation cap still applies.

There is a maximum of 200 points from upvotes per day.

Losing points to bounties does not increase that maximum.

The reputation counter tends to [behave strangely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69174/inconsistent-reputation-count-after-bounty) after setting a bounty even for accepted answers, but that is nothing to worry about.

Comment: so if you get 25 upvotes, which is 250 reputation, and you offer a 50 rep bounty, should your total for the day be +200 or +150?

Comment: @hvgotcodes +150. The last 5 upvotes never count, the bounty doesn't change that

Comment: i don't get many +200 days.  and i chose the SECOND time ever to offer a bounty (offered the bounty before I got the votes).  The Irony is killing me....

Comment: @hvgotcodes: remember, it is better to give than to receive.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't earn it, you can't spend it. Basically, if you reach the cap you may as well forget that any of that *left over* rep exists.