# Does offering bounties set you back on epic/legendary badges?

Tags: support, bounties, daily-reputation-badges

From what I read at the [badges description question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/177950), regarding the 3 daily limit badges:

- Earned at least 200 reputation [in a single day/on 50 days/on 150 days]
- All positive reputation activities, including up votes, accepted answers, bounties, and suggested edits count towards this badge **except** for association bonuses, which do not count. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526))
- Down votes cast or received do not count towards this badge. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103))

I take it that **offering** a bounty falls under this 3rd rule, right? I know offered bounties [does not raise my cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69727/can-you-use-unearned-reputation-above-rep-cap-for-bounties/69735#69735) (ex.: yesterday I got +230 at SOpt - 2 accepted and 26 upvotes - offered a bounty of 50, ended the day with +180), but I'm unsure if  the fact that I got 200+ during the day (1st and 2nd rules) is enough to count toward the badges.

Is my reasoning correct? Sorry if this seems like a duplicate question, I've read the linked references but wanted a clarification for this specific case (which AFAIK was not covered there).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [epic badge page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) here on MSE (where bounties are plentiful among high rep users), the last user to be awarded the badge (as of today, obviously) was Shadow Wizard on December 30, 2013.

Since I don't have access to his /reputation page, I looked at his [reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=reputation&sort=graph). Manually counting all the days he reached at least 200, by December 30, 2013, he had only reached it 40 times.

I conclude (but didn't verify) that the missing 10 days were days he hit rep cap, offered a bounty, and ended the day earning less than 200. But those days still counted.

So to answer your question, **offered bounties do not set you back on badge progress**

Comment: This could also be explained by downvotes (which are quite common in Meta), but I think you're right: I got curious after reading your answer, so I wrote [a small query at Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/205830/days-in-which-rep-cap-was-reached-bounty-was-offered?UserId=152859) to verify this. It turns out (if I didn't make any mistake) he reached 200+ in 53 different days, of which in 10 there was a bounty offered - pretty consistent with what you describe... :)

Comment: very nice query!